# How do I get a question reopened?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

Ok. So, it was a badly written question. The OP wasn't clear about what he wanted, but I was able to coax it out of him and rewrite the question. It's still not a *great* question, but it's a good one. My real issue is that it should not have been marked a duplicate. The duplicate question is no where remotely close to what the OP was asking, although I do see why reviewers might have thought so.

My question is, how can I go about giving this guy a shot at getting an answer? I'm fairly new myself and don't know how to ask to have a question reopened.

This is the [question as it is now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23413727/3198973) and this is the so called ["duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873673/sql-to-access-linked-server).

Comment: I've reopened it. I agree it's not a duplicate of that at all.

Comment: ^^^ that's how ... :)

Comment: Same issue, and the moderator probably understand what I'm trying to do, but he won't propose an edit or two.  Why does @AndrewBarber need to be such a pain, and not try to help instead of just close the question?  We all have a learning curve, some are just deeper than others.

Comment: @IGotRoot If you wish to actually ask the community to review your question, make a new post here and explain it. But I recommend an open mind and a better attitude if you do. Leaving a comment on someone else's post won't help. The community is more than welcome to override my decision.

Comment: @AndrewBarber so what you're saying is that I should create an identical question, and get it linked here?

Comment: @IGotRoot  No, I'm saying you should ask a *unique* question here (on Meta) asking for a review of your closed question by the community, and explain why you think it should be reopened. If people agree with you, it'll be reopened very quickly.

Comment: @IGotRoot If you notice, I linked to the question I was disputing on the main site in this meta question. You should do the same in a new question. Alternatively, there is other good advice in [Andrew Barber's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253278/3198973) to my question.

Answer (score 10):

I've reopened [the question you note](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23413727/3198973). I agree it's not a duplicate there at all.

---

There are a few things that can help get a question reopened, more generally speaking. There is a reopen queue that users of certain reputation go through. Things that trigger posts showing up there:

1. This one you'd already done here: The post being edited. You can edit in a *useful* clarification to cause this.
2. Reopen votes being cast. One does need enough reputation to do that.
3. Visit one of the [chatrooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) where the topic is relevant, and inquire about it there. **<sup>1</sup>**

Finally, there are two other options that should generally only be used for issues where the reopen queue does not work, and you *really* think it should be reopened:

1. You've done this one, too: post here. People will look it over.
2. Flag the post for moderator attention with the "needs moderator attention", other, reason, and explain.

Both of these last two options should be used fairly sparingly. Also, the second one might take some time... sometimes a very significant amount of time. I'm talking days (or even weeks), considering our current moderator queue volume. But sometimes it does happen slightly faster. It'll seem random at times.

---

<sup>**1** I'm not a regular visitor of topic-related chatrooms. Note that the expectations of content to be posted in them can vary widely. Also, some people feel that trolling the chatrooms with vote requests (up/down, close/open) feels a bit 'dirty'. But for the sake of completion - and because it *can be* a way to do what you ask - I've added it.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation (and the assistance).

Comment: When you mention _"The post being edited. You can edit in a useful clarification to cause this."_: is the "this" (= a question is reopened) automatic? In other words: does the fact that a closed question is edited i) reopens the question without further actions from anyone ii) or is it added to some kind of queue called "questions which were closed and later edited - have a look if it should be reopened"?

Comment: @woj It's the latter. The reopen review queue includes questions which have been edited since being put on hold, and includes tools to view the changes made.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Thank you, it is now clear. I hope that the reopen review queue is not too large (akin the moderator queue you mention)

Comment: @woj Nope; the review queues clear fast, except the close queue. :)